# Faulty GPS data on Serial Monitor

Tags: gps, serial, usb, rs232

I am trying to interface Stonex S900A GPS with nVidia TX2 which has ROS melodic installed. The GPS data cable is a DB9 type (RS232). I connected a DB9 to USB converter with the cable and connected it to the USB port of TX2. I intend to use nmea_driver_navsat ros package to read the GPS data. However, when trying to monitor the GPS data on a serial monitor (such as puTTY or CuteCom), I am getting messages in the following format: \

[image: error image] \

Could it be an issue with the serial driver? When I connect the same GPS with the same cable to another system, I get valid information on the serial monitor. What could be the issue here?

Comment: This could be many things, though it doesn't look too bad to me. 

Try these steps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42376/reading-from-serial-from-linux-command-line to get the data directly off the wire. This will tell you the format. NMEA should be ASCII, as you well know. If it's not ASCII, then either it's not sending you what you think it is, or you're not reading it correctly. At least with "pure cat" we can see what is in the buffer.

Try also the ros utility directly, rather than expecting to eyeball the output. See if that works.